# CSS cannot fade out and then hide

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a css class and animation which will make a div (and it's contents) fade out or move, but ultimately, the div to have `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`

My effort is not working! I can get it to either animate, or to appear to be "removed"

This crude example demonstrates the issue

```css
.hide {

    animation-name:fadeOut;
    animation-duration:1s;
    /*visibility: hidden;
    display: none;*/
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: -100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="hide">
    <div style="padding:20px;background:orange;">
        <div style="padding:5px;background:azure;">
            My content
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I also tried updating the CSS to

```
to {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

And also on  https://jsfiddle.net/

As you can see, in the CSS I have commented out the hiding part (although the opacity makes it hidden).

Is it possible to apply the fadeout and then update the `visibility` and `display` without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` so that the element you're animating stays on the last (key)*frame*, and it doesn't start over or refresh to the beginning.

Learn more about [**animation-fill-mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

Another way to write this animation:

```
.hide {
  animation: fadeOut 1s forwards;
}
```

```css
.hide {
    animation-name:fadeOut;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* added */
    /*visibility: hidden;
    display: none;*/
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: -100%;
        height: 0; /* added */
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="hide">
  <div style="padding:20px;background:orange;">
    <div style="padding:5px;background:azure;">
      My content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

   <div>
 Other content
   </div>
```

---

### Scrollbar fix

A possible solution to the *scrollbar issue* is to bring the hidden element back to the initial position with `margin: 0;` (or whatever the initial margin was):

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }

    99% {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: -100%;
        height: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: 0; /* added */
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but this doesn't address the visibility and display issue (although it can suffice for my needs if I make some changes). For example, make the margin-left `margin-left:500%` and you will notice the horizontal scroll bar persists. If it were to then become hidden etc, the scroll bar will (I hope) be removed

Comment: I've been searching around and everywhere they will tell you that you can't animate `display`, but then it hit me: `height: 0;`! I updated the answer above :) I will also add a solution to the scroll bar issue.